# How to Auotmate Combo box for makemytrip as I am able to insert the value but once the focus is moved value is erased from the combobox

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

How to Auotmate Combo box for makemytrip as I am able to insert the value but once the focus is moved value is erased from the combobox

[image]

Comment: Destination City combobox field need to handle

Comment: what code are you currently using ?  - Also have you tried with Sendkeys ?

Comment: Please post the code that isn't working, so we can see what not to suggest...

Answer (score 1):

Try use `Click` first on that `WebEdit` (or maybe `WebElement`) object. Then, use `SendKeys` method to insert desired value. One potential issue here is that the value may still disappear even you use `SendKeys`, if so, try to send the string one by one. Google has lots of sample codes about `SendKeys` and sending string one character by one character.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a `WebEdit` object, you might find it works best if you use the `WebEdit("whateveritscalled").Type myDestinationString` operation rather than `Set` or `SendKeys`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, I am setting the values using the Elementid,it should work-

```
Browser("MakeMyTrip, India's No").Page("MakeMyTrip, India's No").Object.getElementById("from_typeahead1").value = "New Delhi, India (DEL)"
Browser("MakeMyTrip, India's No").Page("MakeMyTrip, India's No").Object.getElementById("to_typeahead1").value = "Mumbai, India (BOM)"
```